# Correct approach to symlink or mount bind two directories on internal storage

Tags: root-access, mount, nexus-5x

I have data from an app I would like to be synced. It writes into a directory, and and has no settings for what dir.
I would like it to write to a different dir, one that is synced.

I'm on a nexus 5x, running stock 8.1.0 fully updated.
I have root.
I'm trying to make things written to `/storage/self/primary/sleep-data` go to `/storage/self/primary/sync/phone/sleep-data`

`ln -s` doesn't work, I'm thinking a filesystem issue, though looking through the output of `mount` it wasn't clear what the filesystem actually is. `/storage/self` is mounted as `tmpfs`.

`mount -o bind /storage/self/primary/sleep-data /storage/self/primary/sync/phone/sleep-data`

This works, but only as root.

I did try `mount -o bind,shared` with and without namespace seperation set in supersu, as suggested [by Rob W](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151969/how-to-make-bind-mounted-mount-o-bind-folders-visible-for-non-root-users#comment216665_151969)

<strike>I suspect it's related to this: [How to "mount --bind" directories in Android 4.4?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102163/how-to-mount-bind-directories-in-android-4-4)</strike>

That does have a workaround, but it's looking like I'm approaching this the wrong way.

That seems to be related to external SD cards only.

What is the android way to solve this problem?